# Generating table with Grids and Map in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, web

I'm having a `Box` inside a `Grid item`, and currently the `Box` is attached to the top left of the Grid [Like this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ul6T.png). Now I want to make the Box stay in the center of the Grid. I have tried justify, justifyContent, align, alignItems and none of them worked. Please help me

Here is my code:

```
const singleBox = {
    border: 1,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderRadius: 16,
    width: 485,
    height: 300,
    align: "center",
    justifyContent: "center", 
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    display: "flex",
}

const GridCell = {
    align: "center",
    justifyContent: "center", 
    alignItems: "center",
    position: "absolute",
    display: "flex",
}

function SingleBox({props}) {
    // console.log(props)

    return(
        <Grid item md = {4} css = {GridCell}>
            <Box css = {singleBox}>
                <p>{props.name}</p>
            </Box>
        </Grid>
    )    
}
```

Here is the code in the App.js

```
const singleRow = {
    height: 350,
    // margin-right: 50,
    marginLeft: 50,
}
<Grid container  style = {singleRow}>
 {personRow}
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you've set the position of the box to absolute. When you set the position to absolute then it will stay there unless you offset it.

Remove

position: "absolute"

from singleBox styles and then check.